# Ionic cannot get live reload option on attached android device to work

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Just started working with Ionic the other day, installed most recent version of framework and all required dependencies on my 2015 Macbook Air running El Capitan.

Everything seems to be working OK with the exception of this issue:

When trying to use the live reload option for development with my usb-connected android phone (via command "ionic run android -l"), I receive the following error message on my phone:

Webpage not available

The webpage at http://[local IP and port of my computer] could not be loaded because:

net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

Note:  I don't receive this message when I leave out the -l option.

I know that others have had this issue and I have read virtually all related articles that come up in a google search, but I am still at a loss for a solution.

Some have said this has to do with default restrictions imposed with Cordova whitelist plugin.  I tried the changes specified in the below article but to no avail.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

I've tried all other fixes that come up from a google search but without success.  As a developer (even a relatively new one) I expect this as par for the course, but the frustration is starting to sink in.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: have you tried allowing absolutely everything? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src * 'self' data:; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

Answer (score -1):

I think you should see this link: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/